# Can we imagine having a computer keyboard that recharges itself through mechanical utilization?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, electricity

Silly question here.

I have a debate with my father, and while I am decent at high school level physics, both he and I cannot determinate through calculus which of us is wrong.

Basically, he had the idea that perhaps, through simple mechanical utilization, a wireless keyboard can be charged and used, without any other energy source. (The keyboard can have a battery that can be recharged through the said mechanical utilization though), I have the intuition that the idea is interesting, but physically problematic.

With simple research, I have seen that an idle keyboard has a consumption of $1W$, and a used keyboard will use between $1.5$ and $2.5W$.

So, we have specific questions:

- **Is collecting the mechanical energy from the keyboard doable ?**
- **And if yes, how much energy can typing on a keyboard's key produce ?**
- **How it may impact the overall comfort of the user ?**

I have multiple difficulties to answer these myself. How can I know how much a person can generate through typing, how much energy will be lost in the process of using a battery, etc..?

(This is not a concept that I try to sell or anything, this is a mere thought experiment that I wanted to share and resolve, please do not take it too seriously)

Comment: I see two close votes, would any close voters please let OP know what they think can be improved with his question and not just silently close it.

Comment: @doublefelix 1. needs more focus, 2. needs clarity.

Comment: Take a look at wireless, self-powered doorbells. Note how the travel (and likely pressure) button differs from battery-powered doorbells.

Comment: I recommend moving to Engineering SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is fairly simple. All you need to do is build a piezoelectric generator under each key. These generate electricity with each push. With this the element is stretched or vibrated with each push and this generates electricity. Do a Google search and you will find much more.

Comment: Your comment helped me to find this project : https://ryanstinebaugh.com/Pages/Keyboard.html that go a bit deeper in the subject, thank you very much !

Answer (score 4):

You move 1 key about 5mm. if you use a force of 2N one stroke on a key  will give you 0.01J so you would need 100strokes per s to get 1W if the mechanical energy  is 100%  transformed in electrical energy. So now you  can discuss it, even using 4 times the force does not help much.
Why not using a dynamo by pedaling with your feet?

Comment: Great answer and I buy the 5mm. But could you provide half an argument for the 2N estimation. I have no idea about the order of magnitude that is realistic.

Comment: I put 100g on the spacebar it just moved, so I estimated I could easily push with 2N.

Comment: @trula RSI is also a thing. Even piano keys are significantly lighter. Ever hit a piano key and think "that's pretty heavy"?